# Add jasDB jar files to IntelliJ gradle android project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I use IntelliJ with gradle for android projects.

I downloaded the jasDB-android jars to src/main/libs, and right clicked on the folder and added as a library.

I get errors like: Gradle: error: package nl.renarj.jasdb.api does not exist

How can I add jar files?

Comment: Is this IntelliJ or Android Studio? You say so in your question but I just want to be clear. If it's Android Studio, what version is it?

Comment: it's IntelliJ. I "solved" this problem by using an Android Application module instead of the gradle project, but I want to try gradle.